# Why is referencing/borrowing needed in this case?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and just played around with some code:

```rust
fn array_leaders(arr: &[i32]) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut res = Vec::new();
    for (i, left) in arr.iter().enumerate() {
        let right = arr.iter().skip(i+1).sum();
        if left > right { res.push(*left) };
    }
    res
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&i32: Sum<&i32>` is not satisfied
    --> src/lib.rs:5:42
     |
5    |         let right = arr.iter().skip(i+1).sum();
     |                                          ^^^ the trait `Sum<&i32>` is not implemented for `&i32`
```

Now, I've figured out that i could just add an `&` to the right variable in the if statement:

```rust
        if left > &right { res.push(*left) };
```

which solves the problem. I would like to understand why though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `left` has type `&i32` (generated via `.iter()`) but `right` as type `i32` (generated by `sum()`).

We could compare `*left` against `right` (two `i32`).

Rust also enables the comparison through references: `left` against `&right` (two `&i32`).

The same level of indirection must be present on both sides of the comparison.

The short example below tries to illustrate this.

Moreover, as stated in a comment, Rust tries to deduce the types that are not strictly imposed (when some alternatives exist).
Here, the type of `left` is imposed by `.iter()` but the return type of `sum()` could be deduced.
Then Rust tries to find an implementation of `sum()` that matches `&i32` because this result will be compared against `&i32` (`left`). This cannot be found here, thus the error.

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 5;
    for b in 3..=7 {
        let r_a = &a;
        let r_b = &b;
        let cmp1 = a < b;
        let cmp2 = r_a < r_b;
        let cmp3 = *r_a < *r_b;
        println!("{} < {} --> {} {} {}", a, b, cmp1, cmp2, cmp3);
    }
}
/*
5 < 3 --> false false false
5 < 4 --> false false false
5 < 5 --> false false false
5 < 6 --> true true true
5 < 7 --> true true true
*/
```

Comment: And to be perfectly clear, the error occurs on the line `right` is declared since Rust is trying to make all of the traits line up, and the resolution fails there. It doesn't say "I can't compare `i32` and `&i32`". It says "I needed a `&i32`, so I tried to make `sum` return a `&i32` and it didn't work", since that's the way the compiler thinks.

Comment: thanks a lot, made things much clearer!